# Decrease one columns height bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, flexbox

What I want to achieve is a footer design like this with bootstrap:

[image]

I already have managed to get the left column (Red Background ) of the footer set up. The problem is, that somehow I can't style the Right column (Black Background). As soon as I set the height to 70%, the column height shrinks to the content. I see that this has to do with no height being set to the parent container. But how can I set a fixed height, and still maintain responsiveness? With media queries?

Also as soon as I set the display to flex for the right-column that contains the 2 rows ( One with the links, and one with the white logo), the rows get displayed as columns next to each other. If I dont do so, the content alignment has no effect.

Can anyone help me with this issue? It seems like I missed some important point about the grid system and display utilities.

This is what it looks right now:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
<footer class="mt-auto" role="contentinfo">
<div class="container-fluid h-100">
    <div class="row footerContainer d-flex h-100">

        <div class="footerLeftCol col-12 col-md-7">

            <div class="row pl-5 justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-12 mt-3 mb-3"><img
                            src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/logo_white.png"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="row align-items-center text-center">

                <div class="col-12 col-md-6 contactColLeft">
                   
                </div>

                <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
                   
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row text-center mt-3 pb-3">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <a><i class="fab fa-instagram fa-lg mr-2"></i></a>
                    <a><i class="fab fa-facebook-square fa-lg"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-12 copyright">
                <p class="text-center pt-2">&copy; Copyright <?php echo date( 'Y' );  ?> - All rights
                    reserved.</p>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="footerRightCol d-flex col-12 col-md-5">

            <div class="row text-center align-items-center justify-content-center ">
                <div class="col-12 flex-grow-1">
                    <h4> Impressum </h4>
                    <h4> Datenschutz </h4>
                    <h4> Sitemap </h4>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row  flex-grow-1 justify-content-end mr-3 mt-auto text-center">

                <div class="col-6">
                    <h4> Designed by </h4>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6">
                    <img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri()?>/images/logo_fewture.png" style="height: 50px">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set your second column as `display: flex` and define it with `flex-direction: column` and `justify-content-end`.

Put your content inside the second column div, and the content will start to grow from bottom.

```css
.box-1 {
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row border border-primary p-2">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 border border-secondary box-1">Column 1</div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 border border-secondary d-flex flex-column justify-content-end p-2">
      <div class="border border-danger p-2"/>
        <p>As the content is growing</p>
        <p>Justify content end with</p>
        <p>Flex direction column</p>
        <p>Will make content growing up :)</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I need to have the content aligned to center. Also I do not know how to decrease the right columns( Black Background) height to be lower than the left Columns(Red Background) height...

Comment: I would recommend avoiding set the element's height. Instead, let flexbox do it for you.
In this solution, the right column will grow up from bottom to top. So the right column content will always be lower than the left (unless it grows too much).

Then, you can insert a new div with `display: flex` inside the right column div, and put the flexbox attributes to center align the content.